# unwrapping a video tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, tags, forced-unwrapping

I have this:

```
<div class="vid">

<video> bla bla bla </video>

</div>
```

I have to unwrap this video tag, so I tried:

```
$( "video" ).unwrap();
```

The result in the console window is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
message: "undefined is not a function"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Any clue?

Tks a lot!

Comment: Is jQuery loaded on your page? Is the error a result of calling `$(...)`, or `.unwrap()`? Try doing `var $vid = $('video'); $vid.unwrap();` and see on which line that error occurs.

Comment: are you executing it after DOM becomes ready (e. g. inside `$(document).ready(function(){....})`?

Comment: ajp15243, the answers are:

Comment: D.fn.D.init {0: video, length: 1, prevObject: D.fn.D.init, init: function, jquery: "1.2.6", size: function…}
0: video
length: 1
prevObject: D.fn.D.init
__proto__: Object

Comment: and   $vid.unwrap();
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: It is inside 'ready'

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `$` is not defined. Are you sure jQuery is loaded?

You might try `console.log`ing these:

```
console.log(window.jQuery); // What's the output of this?
console.log($); // What's the output of this? 
console.log(jQuery('video')); // What's the output of this?
```

That's a good way to debug your problem.

Comment: It should be noted that the last one will fail with `TypeError: undefined is not a function` if jQuery isn't loaded on the page.

Comment: Here the outputs                                                     (1) 
function (a,b){return new D.fn.init(a,b)} 
undefined

(2) 
function (a,b){return new D.fn.init(a,b)} 
undefined

(3)
D.fn.D.init {0: video, length: 1, prevObject: D.fn.D.init, init: function, jquery: "1.2.6", size: function…}
0: video
length: 1
prevObject: D.fn.D.init
__proto__: Object
undefined

Comment: There are more jquery's running ok

Comment: And yes, there was a problem with the sequence of jquery's. Now I put the not functional block at the first.